# Passing an array into python argument from bash

Tags: python, bash, arguments

I have some python script `foo.py` with many arguments. Inside that script I am using `argparse import ArgumentParser` to parse them.

I want to pass an array as the value of one of them from bash. I have tried:

```
python foo.py --arg1=1 --arrArg=[1,2] --arg3=x
```

when I print them inside the script I get:

> arg1=1
>
> arrArg=['1',',','2']
>
> arg3=x

How do I pass the arry as numbers from bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the script yourself, and only yourself, then you can use [`eval()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval). But watch out, this is **not** a very safe function. Don't *ever* use this when you don't know what the input is.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--arr',
                help='Array of integers')

args = parser.parse_args()
data = eval(args.arr)
print(type(data))
print(data)
```

Otherwise, use the `nargs='+'` argument for argparse:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('--arr', nargs='+', type=int,
                    help='Array of integers')

args = parser.parse_args()
data = args.arr
print(type(data))
print(data)
```

And call your script with `python foo.py --arr 1 2 3 --bla blablabla`

Comment: I have actually used `nargs=n`, where n is my array length but only thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways you can do this: using `nargs` or using `action=append`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# You can specify number of elements in an array.
# '+' == 1 or more.
# '*' == 0 or more.
# '?' == 0 or 1.
# An int is an explicit number of elements to accept.
parser.add_argument('--nargs', nargs='+')

# To make the input integers
parser.add_argument('--nargs-int-type', nargs='+', type=int)

# Using `action=append`. But out must provide the flag for every
# input. And you can use type=int here as well.
parser.add_argument('--append-action', action='append')

# To show the results
for _, value in parser.parse_args()._get_kwargs():
    if value is not None:
        print(value)
```

And the results will look like this:

```
$ python arg.py --nargs 1234 2345 3456 4567
['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567']

$ python arg.py --nargs-int-type 1234 2345 3456 4567
[1234, 2345, 3456, 4567]

$ # Negative numbers are also handled
$ python arg.py --nargs-int-type -1234 2345 -3456 4567
[-1234, 2345, -3456, 4567]

$ python arg.py --append-action 1234 --append-action 2345 --append-action 3456 --append-action 4567
['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567']
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs